# How to add X-Frame-Options="sameorigin" to Magento 1.7?

Tags: magento-1.7

We are planning an upgrade to our store within 2-3 months, but in the interim, I need to pass a PCI compliance scan of our website. This is the only error that I cannot seem to figure out how to install.

I need to add X-Frame-Options="sameorigin" (To prevent clickjacking) to the headers of all of my website pages.  Where would I implement such code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality was [implemented in Magento CE 1.9.0.0](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1900-changes), so you won't have to worry once you upgrade.

In the meantime, you can implement this easily at the server configuration level - just remove it when you don't need it any more.

More information and examples [are available here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).